# Dojo Charting Problem with markers

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

Is it possible to move `markers` pointer displayed in dojo chart with animation?

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution might be like this.

//below is for simple animation for markers

```
chart1.connectToPlot("default", function (e){
var ele = e.shape ? e.shape.rawNode ? e.shape.rawNode : false  : false;
    if(!ele) return;
if(e.type == "onmouseover")
ele.setAttribute("stroke-width", 3)
else if (e.type == "onmouseout")
ele.setAttribute("stroke-width", 1.5)
}
```

you can use this function for some complex animation of raw svg node. Instead of calling setAttrbuite in the above code , call the below function passing the raw svg node to it.

```
function cmplxAnimForRawNode(RawSVGNode){
        var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";       
        var node = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");
        var atts = {attributeType:"XML", attributeName:"transform", type:"scale" ,from:"1" ,to:"0" ,dur:"5s", fill:"freeze"}
        for(name in atts) {
            node.setAttributeNS(null, name, atts[name]);
        }
        RawSVGNode.appendChild(node);

        }
```